# What should we do with the afd tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

The [afd](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/afd) tag refers to the FAA's Airport/Facility Directory, which [was renamed to the Chart Supplement](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2016/march/15/familiar-green-afds-disappear) in March 2016.

Right now we only have 4 questions tagged [afd](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/afd) but what should we do with them? Should we create a new tag and keep [afd](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/afd) as a synonym? If so, what should the new tag be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say create `chart-supplement` with `afd` as synonym, plus added description of the change.

Comment: yeah, I can't think off another on, so...

Comment: Since the rest of the world calls these "Chart Supplements" I've made the change and created the synonym as described above. I've also created a tag wiki which will explain the change for us crusty old codgers who will continue calling it "The AFD" because it's faster/easier to say than "The chart supplement".

Comment: @voretaq7 Shouldn't it be `a-fd` though? As it is A/FD.

Comment: @ymb1 I've seen AFD more commonly than A/FD in online shorthand. I'm also hesitant to set a precedent of tags beginning with `a-` because sometimes people like to make sentences out of tags (we'll start getting tags like `a-flight-control-surface`, and then I will become angry and hit people :)